# Return to the caller function MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, branch, mips, mips32, mips64

I've just started learning MIPS assembly and I can't figure out, how to conditionally return to the `caller` procedure. An example will make my question clearer. I have a procedure `caller`, which does something before calling `multiply`, I want this procedure to execute `other things` after `multiply` is finished. I know how to use conditions to jump to the labels, but instead of `beq $t3, 80, caller` I want to return to the `caller`, just after `jal multiply`. I know that, to return you have to use `jr $ra`, but can I call it using a condition?

```
caller:
    doing_somehing
    jal multiply
    other_things    

multiply:
    beq $t3, 80, caller

    lw $t4, array($t3)
    mul $t4, $t4, $t1
    sw $t4, array($t3)

    addi $t3, $t3, 4
    j multiply
```

Assembly should behave like this C code:

```
void caller()
{
    doing_something();
    multily();
    other_things();
}

void multiply()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 80)
    {
        someUnrelated();
        i += 4;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ... but can I call it using a condition?

Unfortunately no.

Only few CPUs (like 8080-compatibles (8080, Z80, 8085) and ARM) allow condition-based return.

You'll have to use a `beq` instruction that jumps to a `jr $ra` instruction.